# Why does job appear to be stuck in queue on IBMQ backend?

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

I have submitted a batch of circuits to `ibmq_vigo` using the `IBMQJobManager` and the batch is correctly split properly into multiple jobs(as viewed on the dashboard), however the job at the front of the queue appears stuck at the front for multiple hours. The backend does not appear to be in reserve mode and I did not have this issue when I successfully executed the same batch of circuits on `ibmq_rochester`.

Does anyone know what might be the issue?
Also this is my second unsuccessful attempt at executing on `ibmq_vigo`.

Comment: It might be due to the long queue of jobs in `ibmq_vigo`. Right now (32 min after your post) I see 44 waiting jobs! Also, `ibmq_rochester` backend is not listed in IBMQ dashboard at the moment of talking. When did you try it?

Comment: the issue is that the first 30+ jobs are all mine. And my job at the front of the queue has been at the front for hours, almost as if `ibmq_vigo` is in reserve/priority mode, which it isn't.

Comment: if you have access to `ibmq_rochester` it means you are part of an institution that has access to premium IBM Quantum devices with a specific priority. On the contrary, `ibmq_vigo` is an open device. It means that you are sharing this resource with the whole world. This may explain why you are experiencing longer queue time on `ibmq_vigo` than on `ibmq_rochester`.

Comment: In addition, the "queue position" you see, either on the dashboard or using Qiskit, is within the scope of your provider. This means even if your job has a queue position of 1, someone else can jump the line if they have higher priorities. And since it's a fair share queuing system, the more you use the lower your priority becomes.

Comment: @jyu00 thanks for that, do you know how I can get the global queue position, possibly from within qiskit?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to get the global queue position right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime that happens. The controlled electronic might got a reboot during while your jobs were in queue or something of that sort... You can try to cancel your jobs and resubmitted them to see if that fixes it. Note that if you running jobs through Aqua, like performing QAOA or VQE, you can cancel the current jobs and they will create a replacement job automatically.